# Is there an easy way to create a user login?

Tags: django

I would like to have normal users (not admins) who can log in.

By default when doing a project in Django it is enough to create a superuser and you can already authenticate and manage the site, also if I created a model named `Question` I can create, edit and delete questions from the admin dashboard ([like in the tutorial part 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/)) adding just this code:

```
from .models import Question

admin.site.register(Question)
```

I would like to replicate this, I mean, to have a similar login template with normal users and a dashboard where these normal users can see, create, edit and delete `Question` instances that belongs to them, ie., where they can manage only their questions, but obviously making them not be able to edit other users or groups, how could I do it? would it be difficult?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The first step is create the user, once you have your users, you have to create relations for them so you can filter by user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Question(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

and in your view you just filter `Question.objects.filter(user=request.user)` or `User.objects.get(id=request.user.id).question_set.all()` here we are getting all the question for a single user, the next step is try to add, modify or delete following the examples. You don't need to manage permission

Comment: Correct, a foreignkey or onetoone both types of relation of user and question will only display the questions of that particular user.